# Converting String to Message Object Android Application

Tags: java, android

How can I convert a string to an Object of Message Type?

as shown below:

```
String str= "Hello";
Message msg ; // I want to assign str to msg..
```

thanks ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a reference to the `Handler` that will be processing the message:

```
final int MESSAGE_CODE = ...;
Message msg = Handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_CODE, str);
```

If you don't have a reference to the `Handler`, just create a new `Message`, then set the `obj` field:

```
Message msg = Message.obtain();
msg.obj = str;
```

Comment: Its crazy, no one has upvoted u on this.. Most other questions are cryptic, yours is bullseye.

Answer (score -3):

I guess you want to transfer between thread or else.
You can assign str to Message member obj

msg.obj = str;

and send it.

Comment: Incorrect answer.. You should modify it to be more appropriate and correct.